# Deserialize strings and objects using jackson annotations in java

Tags: java, json, jackson

My current json file looks like this:

```
{
  "root": {
    "node1a":[
    ],
    "node1b":[
      "foo",
      "bar"
    ]
  }
}
```

And jackson deserialization:

```
@JsonCreator
class DeserializationClass{

    Map<String, List<String>> nodes;

    DeserializationClass(@JsonProperty("root") final Map<String, List<String>> nodes) {
        this.nodes = nodes;
    }
}
```

However, I want to move to a structure such as

```
{
  "root": {
    "node1a":[
    ],
    "node1b":[
      "foo",
      "bar",
      {
        "key1":"value",
        "key2":"value"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Is it possible to deserialize this using annotations by replacing:

```
Map<String, List<String>>
```

with

```
Map<String, List<AnotherClass>>?
```

Comment: Has my answer was helpful somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Your `node1b` is now a mixed array of objects, so unless you are going to implement a full custom deserializer the best you can get is a `List<Object>`, where some of those objects will be `Map`s.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JsonCreator](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonCreator.html) annotation and two constructors for `POJO` item. In case there is a primitive in array `1-arg` constructor will be used. In case of fully set object `2-arg` constructor will be used. Take a look on below example:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class JsonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File jsonFile = new File("./resource/test.json").getAbsoluteFile();

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        System.out.println(mapper.readValue(jsonFile, DeserializationClass.class));
    }
}


class DeserializationClass {

    Map<String, List<AnotherClass>> nodes;

    @JsonCreator
    DeserializationClass(@JsonProperty("root") final Map<String, List<AnotherClass>> nodes) {
        this.nodes = nodes;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "DeserializationClass{" +
                "nodes=" + nodes +
                '}';
    }
}

class AnotherClass {

    private String key1;
    private String key2;

    @JsonCreator(mode = JsonCreator.Mode.DELEGATING)
    public AnotherClass(@JsonProperty("key1") String value) {
        this(value, null);
    }

    @JsonCreator
    public AnotherClass(@JsonProperty("key1") String key1, @JsonProperty("key2") String key2) {
        this.key1 = key1;
        this.key2 = key2;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "AnotherClass{" +
                "key1='" + key1 + '\'' +
                ", key2='" + key2 + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Which for your `JSON` payload prints:

```
DeserializationClass{nodes={node1a=[], node1b=[AnotherClass{key1='foo', key2='null'}, AnotherClass{key1='bar', key2='null'}, AnotherClass{key1='value1', key2='value1'}]}}
```